# Laravel Relations Should I use hasManyThrough or belongsToMany? Nesting 3 Tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I asked this question before, but formatted it way different and incorrectly.
The deal is, I have 4 tables of which I would like to nest.

I want Measurement containing measurement_data which contains measurement_fields which contains measurement_type (only showing important fields). 
So far, I have everything but MeasurementFields inside of Measurement Data.

My tables:

```
measurements
 - id
 - client_id (not really important now)

measurement_data
 - id
 - measurement_id
 - measurement_field_id

measurement_fields
 - id
 - type_id

measurement_types
 - id
 - name
```

I have tried hasManyThrough and belongsToMany but I can't get either of them to work. This is what I have in my Models now :

**Measurement Model**

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'client_id',
    ];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function clients() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'client_id');
    }

    public function measurement_datas() {
        return $this->hasMany(MeasurementData::class);
    }
    
    public function measurement_fields() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(MeasurementField::class, 'measurement_fields', 'measurement_id', 'measurement_field_id')
        ->withPivot([
            'type_id',
            'name',
            'enabled',
        ]);
    }
```

**MeasurementData Model**

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'measurement_id',
        'measurement_field_id',
        'data',
    ];

    public function measurement() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Measurements::class, 'measurement_id'); 
    }
```

**MeasurementField Model**

```
    protected $table = 'measurement_fields';

    protected $fillable = [
        'type_id',
        'name',
        'enabled',
    ];
    public $timestamps = false;


    public function measurement_type() {
        return $this->belongsTo(MeasurementType::class, 'type_id');
    }
```

**MeasurementType Model**

```
    protected $table = 'measurement_types';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public function measurement_field() {
        return $this->hasMany(MeasurementField::class); 
    }
```

**My Controller MeasurementController**

```
    public function index()
    {
        return JsonResource::collection(Measurement::with(['clients', 'measurement_datas', 'measurement_fields'])->get());
    }
```

I would appreciate any help, because I've been stuck on this for a while now. Thank you :)

Comment: how do you call them in your controller?

Comment: I will edit my question to contain the controller, forgot. One moment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, firstly, your `MeasurementData@measurement` method is using `Measurements` when it should be `Measurement` (singular - to match the class name).

Secondly, the table you reference in a `belongsToMany` should be the pivot table and not the table of the relationship you want. The `withPivot` won't work/be needed as those fields are not part of the pivot table. Also, you only need to define the column names for the relationship if the don't follow Laravel's [naming convention](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure). This is what your `measurement_fields` method can look like:

```
public function measurement_fields()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(MeasurementField::class, 'measurement_data');
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could set up a relationship between `MeasurementData` and `MeasurementField` (if you haven't done so already) and then use [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading). Add the following to your `MeasurementData` model:

```
public function measurement_field()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(MeasurementField::class);
}
```

Then you can load the information using:

```
Measurement::with(['clients', 'measurement_datas.measurement_field.measurement_type', 'measurement_fields'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but, now I get pivot data (measurement_id and measurement_field_id) inside my measurement_fields object. But what I want is to get the info within the measurement_data object so I can reach the name and other fields etc. Ultimately I want a function that disables the field and the data with it so it doesnt show up on my CRUD

Comment: @bgeertsema2000 You can just remove the pivot data in the controller or create a custom resource for this. Alternatively, you could load the field relationship via the data relationship.

Comment: For some reason I only get the foreign keys back from measurement_fields, not the others :
{"data":[{"id":1,"client_id":1,"clients":{"id":1,"clientnumber":"284824367384Ger"},"measurement_fields":[{"id":1,"type_id":1,"name":"test1","enabled":1,"pivot":{"measurement_id":1,"measurement_field_id":1}},{"id":2,"type_id":2,"name":"test2","enabled":0,"pivot":{"measurement_id":1,"measurement_field_id":2}},{"id":3,"type_id":1,"name":"test3","enabled":1,"pivot":{"measurement_id":1,"measurement_field_id":3}}]}

Comment: I can see you're getting `name` and `enabled` in the `measurement_fields` as well. The `pivot` is an extra field that is added when you retrieve a `BelongsToMany` relationship.

Comment: Yeah I get that, But i dont get the data with the fields attached to every data entry
I would like it to display the measurement_field inside the measurement_data

Comment: Like, as of right now I get data and fields beside each other. I want to nest it inside data

Comment: Oh, in that case don't use the `belongsToMany` relationship. Set up a `belongsTo` relationship in `MeasurementData` and load it that way. Sorry, because you mentioned trying `HasManyThrough` and `BelongsToMany` I just assumed you wanted to have that data on the `Measurement` model. I'll update my answer with what I mean.

Comment: That's my bad haha, I will try your updated answer, i'll get back to you :)

Comment: I tried this before also, but I didnt include all the functions like you did in the controller.

Comment: Glad I could help! I find it's always a good idea to try to set up both sides of every relationship when creating a new model just in case you need any one them later down the line :)